# Mixing overprint with blocks of enumerations

Tags: beamer, enumerate, overlays

I'd like to overlay a series of different blocks, each of which includes an enumeration that pauses with each item.  The `overprint` environment handles this pretty well, but it doesn't seem to be mixing with the theme I'd like to use: `Warsaw`.  Here's a minimal example of my problem:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Warsaw}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Test}
  \begin{center}
  text before
  \pause
  \begin{overprint}%
    \onslide<2-3>\begin{center}{
        \begin{block}{Some title here}
        \begin{enumerate}[<+->]
        \item One
        \item Two
        \end{enumerate}
        \end{block}
    }\end{center}
    \onslide<4->\begin{center}{
        \begin{block}{Some title here}
        \begin{enumerate}[<+->]
        \item CHicken
        \item Duck
        \item Rooster
        \end{enumerate}
        \end{block}
    }\end{center}
  \end{overprint}
  text after
  \end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The blocks are overlayed ontop of each other nicely but the bullet points that get generated go haywire.  Here's a screen shot of what happens by the last slide:

[image]

Things work fine if I don't include the pauses between each enumeration item.  Things also work well if I don't use the `Warsaw` theme.

Any thoughts as to why the `Warsaw` theme is corrupting my enumerations?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not just `Warsaw`; using `CambridgeUS`, for example, the problem also appears. Removing the inner `center` environments (which in your concrete example have no real effect) or using `\centering` instead solves the problem:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Test}
  \begin{center}
  text before
  \pause
  \begin{overprint}%
    \onslide<2-3>{%
        \centering
        \begin{block}{Some title here}
        \begin{enumerate}[<+->]
        \item One
        \item Two
        \end{enumerate}
        \end{block}\par}
    \onslide<4->{%
        \centering
        \begin{block}{Some title here}
        \begin{enumerate}[<+->]
        \item CHicken
        \item Duck
        \item Rooster
        \end{enumerate}
        \end{block}\par}
  \end{overprint}
  text after
  \end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

An image of the last slide:

[image]

I am not sure if perhaps the effect that you are trying to achieve is this one (using `overlayarea` instead of `overprint`):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Test}
  \begin{center}
  text before
  \pause
  \begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{3.3cm}
    \only<2-3>{%
        \begin{block}{Some title here}
        \begin{enumerate}[<+->]
        \item One
        \item Two
        \end{enumerate}
        \end{block}}
    \only<4-7>{%
        \begin{block}{Some title here}
        \begin{enumerate}[<+(2)->]
        \item CHicken
        \item Duck
        \item Rooster
        \end{enumerate}
        \end{block}}
  \end{overlayarea}
  text after
  \end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The last slide:

[image]

By the way, you were using `\onslide<2-3>\begin{center}{...}\end{center}` and the proper syntax would be `\onslide<2-3>{\begin{center}...\end{center}}`; this, however doesn't solve the problem in this case; one possible solution is the one I described above.

Comment: Your second suggestion _almost_ does exactly what I want, except it creates only 4 slides instead of 7.  On the last slide, the second enumeration block is completely printed, so you can't walk through the bullet points as they're added.  

I did the `\onslide<2-3>\begin{center{...}}` business since it let me center the blocks on top of each other and let me enumerate the blocks as I wanted, sans the horrible side effect noted.  Putting the center block inside `{..}` ends up with a totally different layout.

Comment: @fozziethebeat please see the second code in my updated answer. Is something like that what you want?

Comment: _oooo_ **yes**, that's exactly what I needed!